# Update foreign key values in foreign table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I want to update foreign key values in a table in the following manner:

```
FK
1 to 5
2 to 6
3 to 7
4 to 1
5 to 2
6 to 3
7 to 4
```

However if I go through the above sequentially as so:

```
update table set fk = 5 where fk=1
```

When I want to update value 5 then id be mixing values with the earlier update statement result which had changed value 1 to 5.

How can I update these values without mixing them with the earlier results.

Comment: I would add the new values and old values to a temp table and update used by joining to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily add a column `Updated BIT` to the table, and when you update a row's value, set this bit to `1` (True - already updated) - and avoid updating those rows that have already been updated!

Step 1: add new column with values `0` (false - not updated yet):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
  ADD Updated BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0) WITH VALUES
```

Step 2: do your updates - respect the `Updated` flag!

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable 
SET fk = 5, Updated = 1
WHERE fk = 1 AND Updated = 0
```

Step 3 : once everything is updated - drop the column again

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
  DROP COLUMN Updated
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an additional column as FreshPrince suggested.  Add new column, set it to the appropriate values, and change the key to the new column.

Another approach may be to use a set of values outside that range.  This would eliminate the need to add and remove columns.  So...

```
update table set fk = 15 where fk=1

1 to 15
2 to 16
3 to 17
4 to 11
5 to 12
6 to 13
7 to 14
```

And then a straight update to subtract 10 from all rows.

```
update table set fk = fk - 10
```

You will need to remove and reinstate the foreign key constraint as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a CASE expression to specify the new values in a single UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET fk=CASE fk
    WHEN 1 THEN 5
    WHEN 2 THEN 6
    WHEN 3 THEN 7
    WHEN 4 THEN 1
    WHEN 5 THEN 2
    WHEN 6 THEN 3
    WHEN 7 THEN 4
END
WHERE fk IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

In this particular case, you could also use:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET fk=(fk+3)%7+1
WHERE fk BETWEEN 1 AND 7
```

Razvan